# sed command help for forward slash

Tags: sed

I have a html line like this

```
  <name> abc </name>
  <name> test </name>
```

Basically any string can be between `<name>` and `</name>` and I have to replace it with word `file : XYZ`

So i tried

```
 sed -i 's/<name>.*<\//name>/<name>file:XYZ<\//name>/g' filename
```

but it throws an error `unexpected char: '\'` on the first back slash. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you replace '/' with '#', there's no need to escape '/'. Modify your command as followed,

```
sed 's#<name>.*</name>#<name>file:XYZ</name>#g' filename
```

And I would suggest you to try the command below,

```
sed 's#\(<name>\).*\(</name>\)#\1file:XYZ\2#g' filename
```

`\1` and `\2` refer to the corresponding matching `\(<name>\)` and `\(</name>\)`. Make sure the output is what you want before `-i` is added.